# How to return stated method type when using try/catch?

Tags: java, try-catch, return-type

In a `switch` statement there are a few cases where I need to parse user input in the form a string into a Date object. I'm using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, but instead of instantiating and calling `parse` for each case, I'd like to encapsulate the date parsing in something of a utility method. It's important that the parse method have exception handling in the event the user inputs a string that doesn't match the pattern passed to the `SimpleDateFormat`.

The problem I'm running into and run into a lot with java is where to place the `return` statement. This is what I have tried:

```
public class MainMenu {

    // a bunch of other stuff

    public static Date parseStrDate(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
        String pattern = "yyyy/mm/dd";
        SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        try {
            Date date = dateParser.parse(dateStr); 
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return date; 
    }
}
```

Implemented this way, the compiler complains that `date` is not defined, since it's only defined in the try subcontext. If I try to return from the `try` context and remove the final `return date;`, the compile complains that it's expecting the `return` statement promised in the method declaration. I've also tried first defining `date` in the scope of the method just below `pattern` expecting it to only be redefined in the `try` statement. No-go there either, though. Beginning to feel like the entire utility method might not be the route to take. Any opinions on how to implement this?

Comment: I think I found the answer: first defining `date` in the scope of the util method was right, but I was using `Date date = dateParser.parse(dateStr);` in the try block. Removing `Date` worked.

Comment: Note as an aside that you should avoid using `Date` in new code; in particular, it makes no sense to parse y/m/d as a `Date`. Use `LocalDate` instead.

Comment: Not what you asked, I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also not what you asked, you should beware of the case of format pattern letters. `mm` and `MM` do not mean the same thing, please double-check.

Comment: How do you want to handle the case of a parse error (date syntax error)? What should your method return? Really asking because I am skeptical towards handling the exception inside the method. The caller may better know how to do that.

Comment: @OleV.V. The requirements for the project that I'm working on require using `Date`, although not `SimpleDateFormat`. The later has proved a waste of time, providing none of the behavior I expected.

Answer (score 2):

This largely depends on what type you're returning, and what the `Exception` *means* in terms of your method's flow.

For example, in the following case, sending a notification of the result has failed, but you can still return the result:

```java
private final Notifier notifier;

public String getResult() {
    final String result = "meow";

    try {
        this.notifier.notifyOf(result);
    } catch (final IOException ioEx) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't notify");
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

In other circumstances, you could return some information about what had happened.  For example, let's say your return type is some `Response` object, which has an `isError` flag on it, then you could do the following:

```java
public Response getResponse(final Request request) {
    try {
        return this.process(request);
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        return Response.forError().withMessage("Couldn't process");
    }
}
```

In the case of the method you've posted about, I would argue that there isn't a sensible response you can give for an un-parseable `String` (there's no default 'date' in most contexts).  So for me, the handling would be something like:

```java
public Date parseDateStr(final String input) {
    try {
        return this.dateParser.parse(input);
    } catch (final ParseException pEx) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't parse date-string: " + input);
    }
}
```

---

Other times, just propagating the `Exception` back to whatever called the method is the appropriate thing to do.  It really depends on the context, and whether there is something sensible you can return or do in the case of that specific `Exception`.

---

As the other answer mentions though, you can get around this compiler warning by declaring (and initialising to some default) the return value outside of the `try` block: but that's not necessarily the best thing to do unless there's some sensible 'default' you can give.

Comment: Good point on propagating the exception back to the source method. I had originally formulated the question to ask about returning a `Date` object or the `ParseException`. Using the `Response` object might be one option. The idea is to require the user to re-input the date when a parse exception is thrown. For now, I've settled on a while loop using `isParse = FALSE; while(!isParsed) {try-catch}` with the successful try block setting isParse to true and the catch reminding user of correct date format. Although, I don't like while loops b/c they are basically locks.

Answer (score 1):

As BeUndead's answer says, there is no sensible default, so throwing an exception is a good choice. I think it would be better to throw a checked exception to force the caller to handle a missing date. The fact that a date may not be returned is part of the function's API and should be exposed.

There is another reasonable choice, which is changing the return type to an `Optional<Date>`.

```
    public static Optional<Date> parseStrDate (String dateStr) {
        String pattern = "yyyy/mm/dd";
        SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        try {
            return Optional.of(dateParser.parse (dateStr));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // it may be useful to log the exception here, if bad dates indicate a wider problem.
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
```

This forces the caller to handle the case of a missing date.

The best solution depends on whether an invalid date is expected (e.g. the string is coming from user input) or really exceptional (e.g. the string is coming from another service and will only be invalid if a bug has been introduced somewhere).

I would also move `pattern` to a `static final` member of the enclosing class. As Nathan Hughes points out, `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe, so we need to create an instance for each call to our method.

It would be better to move to using the new date API:

```
package org.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class DateExample {
    // this class is thread safe
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

    public static Optional<LocalDate> parseStrDate (String dateStr) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(LocalDate.parse(dateStr, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            // it may be useful to log the exception here, if bad dates indicate a wider problem.
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

And a basic test:

```
package org.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestDateExample {
    @Test
    public void testValidDate() {
        assertEquals(LocalDate.of(2021, 7, 4), DateExample.parseStrDate("2021/07/04").get());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvalidDate() {
        assertEquals(Optional.empty(), DateExample.parseStrDate("2021/13/04"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Advice to make dateParser static is not a good idea in general, since SimpleDateFormat is not threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainMenu {
    // a bunch of other stuff

    public static Date parseStrDate (String dateStr) {
        String pattern = "yyyy/mm/dd";
        SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat (pattern);
        Date date = new Date (0L);
        try {
            date = dateParser.parse (dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println (e);
        }
        return date;
    }
}
```

Define `date` outside of the `try`.  Initialize it with a nonsense date or perhaps `null`.  Parse as before.

Removed the `throws` because it does not `throw` because it `catch`es.

Comment: Why catch the exception, print an error, and return a date of 1970-01-01? This is really bad form and shouldn't be endorsed as the right way to fix the code. It's much better to simply let the exception propagate.

Comment: Looking into it more, my question is almost beside the point. My assumptions of what inputs would result in a ParseException were mistaken. My hope was for a simple utility to enforce date formatting, but `SimpleDateFormat` is quite relaxed in what it enforces. For example, the year does not have to be four digits, nor does the month have to be from 1 to 12 nor day from 1 to 31. `2/123/987` is valid input with output = `Mon Nov 12 00:00:00 CST 14`...and no exception.

Comment: @ConnerM. the new java date API seems to be pickier -- see the test in my answer above.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, bad form, Not finished code you or OP or I would write. I wrote to the questioner's question about how to arrange the code to get it to compile while facing error messages re the return and issues of intialization. Suggest something else than 0L if you like, but it has to be initialized or it doesn't compile. Initializing to Now could create confusion. Perhaps the OP was writing quick code, agile programming, etc. I followed the OP's choice on the Exception. Take that up with the OP if you like.